# Getting competitive ban revoked in CS:GO as it was not even a mistake. Is it possible?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I was playing competitive in Dust2 map. SO there were these griefers who when on Terrorist side when having bomb would purposefully throw it in enemy line and die themselves. When it was CT time for my team, my role was to throw incendiary in B side upper tunnel to block their rush. But these guys would just stand in the flames and die. Thus, I got notices about team damage and finally got banned. I was playing fair game helping team, but these griefers's actions got me 7 days ban from competitive.

Is there any way this ban can be revoked?

Comment: That's just a really unfortunate situation. There really isn't anything you can do about that ban... If you happen to get players on your team like that again, I can only suggest taking extra precautions to not shoot them and simply do not use incendiary/frag grenades.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, **no**. According to the knowledge base, cooldowns are non-negotiable, and cannot be removed by Steam support. ([source](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=1203-WJCV-7019))

In this situation, I probably would have avoided using grenades, and reported all of the griefers, since griefing is anticompetitive behavior, and can be grounds for an Overwatch ban.

Comment: I usually report people for griefing in situation wherein they go afk or purposefully block snipers of own team. But dropping bomb and walking into flame was unpredictable.

Comment: @GuruGulabKhatri And actually now that I think about it, if a sufficient number of players did this, it would probably cause a cooldown in one swift instance which is probably what happened so :/

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Valve:

> Counter-Strike: Global Offensive cooldowns and bans are non-negotiable and cannot be removed or reduced by Steam Support.
>
> **If an automated cooldown or ban is determined to have been issued incorrectly, it will automatically be rolled back by our servers.** If you wish to discuss this system with the community, you may do so [here](http://steamcommunity.com/app/730/discussions/).

Source: [Competitive Cooldowns and bans](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=1203-WJCV-7019)